# Calling .Cells(i,j) into .formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I want to call cells using the .cells(i,j) into a .formula

My macro at the moment prints a value/formula into an array of cells.
It works fine for values but I'm having difficulty insert a formula that doesn't return an error.

Here is the relevent line of code

```
Sheets("Stats").Cells(j, i).Formula = SUM(Sheets("Stats").Cells(1, i),Sheets("Stats").Cells(1, i), A3)
```

This is an alternate line for simplicity basically I want to be able to use both the .cells call and the alphanumeric call in the same formula.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

When using .Formula, it expects a string, and it must be formatting the same way that you would enter it into the cell itself without VBA (including the "=" at the beginning). Try

```
Sheets("Stats").Cells(j, i).Formula = _
   "=SUM(" & Sheets("Stats").Cells(1, i).address & _
   "," & Sheets("Stats").Cells(1, i).address & ", A3)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `With` statement in your case can simplify a lot:

```
With Sheets("Stats")    
    .Cells(j, i).Formula = "=Sum(" & .Cells(1, i).Address & "," & .Cells(1, i).Address & ", A3)"
End With
```

**Note**: whenever trying to debug if your formula is correct, use the `Debug.Print`.

In your case, if you put `i = 2` , and below this code:

```
With Sheets("Stats")
    Debug.Print "=Sum(" & .Cells(1, i).Address & "," & .Cells(1, i).Address & ", A3)"
```

You will the following formula in the immediate window:

```
=Sum($B$1,$B$1, A3)
```